# Complex Roots of Unity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I just had a question about complex roots of unity. It's not a computation thing; I know how to find them and I know what they mean. In my class last semester, my professor mentioned that they are more applicable to analysis than they are to abstract algebra.

So, my question is: Do complex roots of unity have a concrete place in abstract algebra? Are they used in more advanced topics in abstract algebra that wouldn't be covered in an undergraduate course?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The nth roots of unity form a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Other than that I don't believe they are particularly notable in abstract algebra.

Comment: Here is a sample. A primitive $n$th root of unity is $e^{2k\pi i/n}$ where $k$ is relatively prime to $n$. The cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_n(x)$ is the product $\prod(x-\alpha_i)$ over the primitive $n$th roots. Show that it has integer coefficients, and is irreducible Find the smallest $n$ for which it has a coefficient other than $0,\pm1$.

Comment: This (ex-)professor would have said that the roots of unity are far more important in algebra than they are in analysis.

Answer (score 3):

In algebra and number theory, cyclotomic fields $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ with a primitive $n$-th root of unity $\zeta_n$ are very interesting. Their ring of integers is given by $\mathbb{Z}[\zeta_n]$, and is used for some cases of Fermat's last theorem. For example, for $n\le 19$ prime this ring has class number $1$, and hence is a factorial ring. This can be used to solve Fermat $x^p+y^p=z^p$ for primes $p\le 19$.

Furthermore Gauss and Jacobi sums involve $n$-th roots of unity and are very useful for algebraic questions in number theory.